# How do Array Pointers behave?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion, function-definition

I was trying to write the code for storing multiplication table in array.

First I wrote the following code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void Multiplication(int arr[][10], int num,int size);

int main(){
    int arr[3][10];
    Multiplication(&arr[0],2,3);
    Multiplication(&arr[1],7,3);
    Multiplication(&arr[2],9,3);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("\n\nMultiplication Table of %d\n\n",arr[i][0]);
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
            printf("%d * %d = %d\n",arr[i][0],j,arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void Multiplication(int arr[][10], int num, int size){
    for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            arr[j][i] = num * (i+1);
        }
    }
}
```

When I was checking whether there is any reduntant part, I removed a little bit of pieces.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void Multiplication(int *arr, int num,int size);

int main(){
    int arr[3][10];
    Multiplication(arr[0],2,3);
    Multiplication(arr[1],7,3);
    Multiplication(arr[2],9,3);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("\n\nMultiplication Table of %d\n\n",arr[i][0]);
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
            printf("%d * %d = %d\n",arr[i][0],j,arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void Multiplication(int *arr, int num,int size){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            arr[i] = num * (i+1);
        }
}
```

Now, I noticed that &arr[0] and arr[0] are behaving same? I wanna know why is it so?

Comment: The first one crashes, not figured out why yet.

Comment: @WeatherVane Me neither, not completely, but `&arr[0]` is a very different animal to `arr[0]`.

Comment: It's crashing because `main` lies to the function about `size` how many rows are available in the array it passes. The second doesn't just pass the array differently: the function is different (only 1 loop nesting and ignores `size`).

Comment: Re "*When I was checking whether there is any reduntant part*", `void Multiplication(...);` is redundant. Simply place the definition of `Multiplication` before `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the question asked:

> I noticed that &arr[0] and arr[0] are behaving same? I wanna know why is it so?

We have

```c
int arr[3][10];
```

`arr[0]` is a `int[10]`, which is to say an array of 10 `int` values.

But it's being treated as a pointer. When an array is treated as a pointer, it produces a pointer to the first element of the array. So this means `arr[0]` is automatically converted to a `int*` pointing to the first element of the first row of `arr` when necessary.

`&arr[0]` means `&(arr[0])`. It produces a `int(*)[10]` (a pointer to an array of 10 `int` values) pointing to the first row of `arr`.

To recap,

- `arr[0]` is a `int[10]` which degrades to a `int*`.

  It points to the first element of the first row of `arr`.
- `&arr[0]` is a `int(*)[10]`.

  It points to the first row of `arr`.

So, `arr[0]` is NOT equivalent to `&arr[0]`, contrary to your assertion.

And this lack of equivalence is why you *had* to change from `&arr[0]` when you when you had `int arr[][10]` (which means `int (*arr)[10]` a parameter), to `arr[10]` when you had `int *arr` as the parameter.

Comment: (There are problems with the code, but that wasn't the question.)

Answer (score 1):

The both programs are incorrect.

You declared a two dimensional array

```
 int arr[3][10];
```

So expressions like this `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, `arr[2]` have the array type `int[10]`. That is they produce the first "row", the second "row" and the third "row" of the two-dimensional array.

In the first program you are calling the function `Multiplication` like

```
Multiplication(&arr[0],2,3);
Multiplication(&arr[1],7,3);
Multiplication(&arr[2],9,3);
```

and within the function there are two nested loops

```
void Multiplication(int arr[][10], int num, int size){
    for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            arr[j][i] = num * (i+1);
        }
    }
}
```

according to the argument specified for the parameter `size` the function deals with a two dimensional array with three elements (rows) of the array type `int[10]` using a pointer to the first element of the array. As a result for the argument expressions `&arr[1]` and `&arr[2]`  there is an access to the memory beyond the original two dimensional array.

You may consider these calls

```
Multiplication(&arr[0],2,3);
Multiplication(&arr[1],7,3);
Multiplication(&arr[2],9,3);
```

like

```
Multiplication( arr, 2, 3 );
Multiplication( arr + 1, 7, 3 );
Multiplication( arr + 2, 9, 3 );
```

The array designator `arr` is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element (row) of the type `int ( * )[10]`.

As you are setting only one "row" within the array then the function can be declared and defined the following way

```
void Multiplication(int arr[][10], int num ){
    for(int j=0;j < 10;j++){
        ( *arr )[j]= num * (j+1);
    }
}
```

and called like

```
Multiplication( arr, 2 );
Multiplication( arr + 1, 7 );
Multiplication( arr +2, 9 );
```

Of you want to set elements of a sub-array then the function can be defined the way it is defined initially but called like

```
Multiplication( arr, 2, 3 );
Multiplication( arr + 1, 7, 2 );
Multiplication( arr +2, 9, 1 );
```

In the second program the function is declared like

```
void Multiplication(int *arr, int num,int size){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            arr[i] = num * (i+1);
        }
}
```

and you are calling it like

```
Multiplication(arr[0],2,3);
Multiplication(arr[1],7,3);
Multiplication(arr[2],9,3);
```

But within the function the parameter `size` is not used. There is used the magic number `10`. And the passed argument `3` does not make a sense.

You should declare the function like

```
void Multiplication(int *arr, int num,int size){
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            arr[i] = num * (i+1);
        }
}
```

and call it like

```
Multiplication(arr[0],2,10);
Multiplication(arr[1],7,10);
Multiplication(arr[2],9,10);
```

Comment: Can you please explain the part where you declared the function taking one row?

Comment: @RACHITMITTAL The array designator arr is converted to pointer to its first "row" of the type int ( * )[10]. So within the function the expression *arr yields the row that is the array of the type int[10]. To access elements of the array (row) you have to write  (*arr )[i]

Comment: Thanks A Lot. Can you cite a resource from where I can master pointers in C? I am having trouble with array using pointers.

Comment: @RACHITMITTAL I advice at first to get a copy of the C Standard Draft. You can find it in the internet.